# Is there such natural number N, such that a^c has 10 distinct digits, for natural a and c >= N?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there such natural number N, such that $a^c$ has 10 distinct digits, for all natural a and all natural $c \ge N$?

Note:

- The question is about the decimal system
- Number a is not a power of 10

For example,
$19^{24}$ contains all decimal digits and the same is true for $19^{25}$, and so far.

Comment: Doesn't your example help answer that?  Or are you looking for $a^c$ that is strictly expressed in only 10 distinct digits. (Each of ten distinct digits present, with no repetition of digits?)

Comment: Um... If $19^{24}$ is such a number, then isn't the answer "yes".  Or do you mean that for *all* $c$ the $a^c$ has all ten digits.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps "for all $a$ and all $c\geq N$"?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yeah, I actually meant that

Comment: @amWhy I am looking whether there exists such N that for any natural number a and for all natural numbers c $\ge$ N, number of distinct digits in $a^c$ is 10

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe so, but also believe it will be very difficult to prove.  One way to justify the belief is to make a probabilistic argument claiming (most of) the digits of $a^c$ (especially the middle ones, which is most of them) are "random".  Then if $a^c$ has $n$ digits the chance any one is missing is about $10 \cdot 0.9^n$.  Now sum over $c$ from $N$ to infinity and the chance for a given $a$ is as small as you want by choosing $N$ large enough.  Now show you can sum over $a$ and still keep the sum small.  The point is that as $a$ gets large $a^c$ has even more digits and even less chance of having one missing.  I have done the first part several times, but not the sum over $a$.

Comment: What does the probabilistic argument look like?

Comment: @JairTaylor:  I was sketching it.  For a given $a$ you find the chance that any $a^c$ is missing a digit from the $10\cdot 0.9^n$ where $n$ is the number of digits.  As $c$ gets larger so does $n$ and you sum from $N$ to infinity, finding that the chance any of them are missing a digit is quite small.  If it isn't very small, increase $N$ and it will get smaller.  That part I have done.  Now we want to sum over $a$, so we want the sums to decrease fast enough the sum converges.  I haven't done that part but am confident it can work.  As long as the sum converges, increasing $N$ can

Comment: make it as small as you want.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that you were omitting the heuristic argument that the digits of $a^c$ should look random and I was curious about that, since that is pretty non-obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\{ 32043^2,32286^2,33144^2,35172^2,35337^2,35757^2,35853^2,37176^2,37905^2,38772^2
 \right\}$$
$$ = \left\{ 1026753849,1042385796,1098524736,1237069584,
1248703569,1278563049,1285437609,1382054976,1436789025,1503267984
 \right\}$$

Are these examples of what you meant?